# Java 8 Lambda: Two Interface with method have same number parameter

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have two interfaces:

```
interface A {
    public void pull(SomeclassA a, SomeclassB b); 
}

interface B {
    public void make(SomeClassM m, SomeclassN n); 
}
```

In each `interface` I have a method with same number of parameters. Then I have a class with methods using both the above two interfaces, that is:

```
public class C {

    public void test(B b) {

    }

    public void test(A a) {

    }

}
```

I need to use the class with Java 8 lambda expression. How will Java recognize which interface is passed in to a method of this class?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    C c = new C(); 
    c.test(
        (a , b ) ->{

        }
    ); 
}
```

Comment: one of the methods gets selected implicitly, for the other one you should either change to inner class creation or try a cast to the proper interface. But you sould definitely change the method names so that they are unique.

Comment: The call is ambiguous: [Ideone](http://ideone.com/NwrbzH)

Comment: @TimothyTruckle: is java 8 lambda expression created without awareness of overloading methods in java.... 
what if I created API that have overloading method?

Comment: looks like. but on the other hand you should not overload methods when you plan to use labda expressions. This significanly harms the readability of your code.

Comment: The intended solution is to redesign C.  Overloading lambda accepting methods is a bad idea most of the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would get a compilation error, since the compiler has no way of choosing between the two overloaded `test` methods.

To fix that you'll have to specify the types of the lambda arguments.

For example :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    C c = new C(); 
    c.test(
        (SomeClassM a , SomeClassN b) -> {

        }
    ); 
}
```

will cause `test(B b)` to be chosen.

Comment: There is no compilation error if I created a class with overloading methods (same name and number parameter, but different in type). I think that is written in java 8 specification...

Comment: @MohammadFajar I tried your code and got a compilation error (I did use different class names instead of SomeClassX). `The method test(B) is ambiguous for the type C`.

Comment: Or it may be `c.test((A)(a, b) ->{ });`

Comment: @Mohammad Fajar: nobody said that you get a compilation error when compiling the class `C` with the overloads. You’ll get a compilation error at the place where you try to make the ambiguous call with an untyped lambda expression. But note that when you compile `C` using `javac` with `-Xlint` option (strongly recommended), you’ll get a `warning: [overloads] test(B) in C is potentially ambiguous with test(A) in C`

Comment: Explicitly typed lambda is good. As a general rule of thumb avoiding overloading is always better.